# Chartkick on rails: change the graph style based on the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, chartkick

I'm using chartkick highchart to shows some graph in rails application. My question is can the style of chartkick graph be changed based on data provided by the chart controller?

for example
this is the code in the chart.html.erb:

```
<%= line_chart charts_cards_history_by_day_path, refresh: 10 %>
```

is there a way to change that code to `<%= bar_chart charts_cards_history_by_day_path, refresh: 10 %>` based on the decision made by the chart controller? So it is up to the controller whether the chart style is line or bar chart.

Thanks,
Randy

the controller source:

```
def cards_history_by_day

      begin

        p_board_id = params['post']['board_id']

        render json:
          [{name: "No. of cards", data: ListsCountPerday.joins(:t_list).where('lists_count_perdays.t_board_id = '+p_board_id+' and
            t_lists.t_list_type_id != 1').group(:date).pluck('date, sum(count)')},
          {name: "Completed", data: ListsCountPerday.joins(:t_list).where('lists_count_perdays.t_board_id = '+p_board_id+' and
            t_lists.t_list_type_id = 5').group(:date).pluck('date, sum(count)')}]

      rescue
        render json: CardHistory.where('t_list_id = -1').group_by_day(:created_at).count
      end

  end
```

The view source:

```
# javascript to handle selection and form submission
<%= javascript_include_tag "charts0" %>

# form for user select prefered data to show
<%= form_tag charts0_cards_history_by_day_path , remote: true do %>
<label for="team_name">Team: </label>
<%= collection_select "post", "authentication_id",
            Authentication.order(:team_name), :id, :team_name, prompt: "Please select"  %>
<label for="team_name">Board: </label>
 <%= grouped_collection_select "post", "board_id",
            Authentication.order(:team_name), :t_board, :team_name, :id, :name, prompt: "Please select" %>
 <%= submit_tag 'Apply', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>

#function to show the chart which data taken from the controller
<%= line_chart charts0_cards_history_by_day_path, refresh:10 %>
```

The javascript source:

```
#javascript to update chart data once form is submitted
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    data = $(this).serialize();

    Chartkick.eachChart( function(chart) {
      chart.updateData(chart.getDataSource() + '?' + data);
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Updated controller source (returned an uninitialized constant error for Chart.last.data at cards_history_by_day.js.erb):

```
def cards_history_by_day

          begin

            p_board_id = params['post']['board_id']

           #call the .js.erb file (based on the JS tutorial given)
           respond_to do |format|
             format.js
           end

          rescue
            render json: CardHistory.where('t_list_id = -1').group_by_day(:created_at).count
          end

      end
```

Comment: Are you using AJAX? Can you add the code of your view and controller?

Comment: hi @KartikeyTanna, please check I have added the view and controller codes

Comment: I don't know much about chartkick but in regular Highcharts (pure JS) you can simply use `update` function: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update So probably if you can get the reference to a chart in your JS code (e.g. by referring `Highcharts.charts[0]` object) your can update the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many Thanks to @Kartikey Tanna who inspired me to answer the question. As mentioned, yes I need to modify @Kartikey Tanna a little bit to make things work.

So in addition to @Kartikey Tanna solution. First, I create a new controller method named setChartsData and leave the cards_history_by_day method as the original (render json):

```
def setChartsData
      begin
        # get post data once the form is submitted
        p_board_id = params['form']['board_id']
        # set global variable to store board id
        @formbid = p_board_id
        # set global variable as decider which chart style will be shown
        @dataCountPd = ListsCountPerday.group(:date).count.count

        respond_to do |format|
          format.js
        end
    rescue
      # do nothing
    end
  end
```

Second, I create setChartsData.js.erb with only to render a partial to an empty div id in the view file:

```
$("#charts_div").html("<%= j render(partial: 'chart') %>");
```

Third, I modify my view file from `<%= line_chart charts0_cards_history_by_day_path, refresh:10 %>` into an empty div like this:

```
<div id="charts_div" class="tab-content">
  <div id="chart_perdays" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
</div>
```

Finally, I create the partial like this:

```
<div id="chart_perdays" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <% if @dataCountPd == 1 %>
      <%= bar_chart charts0_cards_history_by_day_path(bid:@formbid), refresh:10 %>
  <% elsif @dataCountPd > 1 %>
      <%= line_chart charts0_cards_history_by_day_path(bid:@formbid), refresh:10 %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

You can see, if the `@dataCountPd` from the controller method return 1, a bar chart will be shown, else a line chart will be shown. Also, after the bar_chart/line_chart command, there is a controller method to returns data for the graph, this time I add a parameter `bid` for query reason in the method.

Best,
Randy

Answer (score 0):

Just add conditional logic in the view according to the data condition you want to test for example:

```
<% if @data.condition %>
  <%= line_chart charts_cards_history_by_day_path, refresh: 10 %>
<% else %>
  <%= bar_chart charts_cards_history_by_day_path, refresh: 10 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hi, I'm afraid I'm not possible to refresh the page each time controller decide the condition. Because, the decision based on a user input and when the user submit the input, the graph controller only render the json graph data (not refresh the page). And a javascript help its update the graph data based on user input, but I can't found how to change the graph style. In other words, can we do the @neydroid condition with javascript? Because maybe it is only the possible solution in my situation. At the moment the javascirpt is like this:

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, make an AJAX call and render a `.js.erb` view in response. The response of `.js.erb` template will be Javascript which will be executed on client side.

The following is the rough example using your code to explain the concept. You will have to modify it to make it work.

First, let's create a `div` in which we want to render the chart dynamically.

Replace the following line:

```
<%= line_chart charts0_cards_history_by_day_path, refresh:10 %>
```

With:

```
<div id="cards_history_by_day_chart"></div>
```

Then, let's create a partial which contains the code to render the chart. This partial will be called from our `.js.erb` view.

// `chart.html.erb`

```
<%= line_chart charts0_cards_history_by_day_path, refresh:10 %>
```

Then, under `cards_history_by_day` method instead of `render json` you can create a `.js.erb` view.

So after each AJAX call, the `.js.erb` view send JS to be executed on the client side.

// `cards_history_by_day.js.erb`

```
Chartkick.eachChart( function(chart) {
      chart.updateData(chart.getDataSource() + '?' + <%= Chart.last.data %>);
    });
$("#cards_history_by_day_chart").html("<%= j render(partial: 'chart') %>");
```

Here you can see that I have replaced `data` in your js with the record in `erb` tag.

You might also like to use conditional rendering in your `cards_history_by_day` method.

```
if condition_match
  render bar_chart
else
  render line_chart
```

In case it is not clear, a tutorial can help: https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy

Comment: Hi @Kartikey Tanna, I have tried your solution. However, when the file .js.erb is called by the controller it returns uninitialized constant error for Chart.last.data. Where do I need to put and set that variable? and is that for the graph data content? I have add updated controller source based on your suggested solution step.

Comment: Yes, that is for the chart data. You were using `data = $(this).serialize();` earlier. But now as it is being rendered from the server, you can take the data from the server. Earlier you were returning some data under `render json` from your controller. Was that the updated data for the graph? I did not see how you were making an AJAX call.